# Internal implementation of InputStream, HashMap and ArrayList?

Tags: java

How **InputStream**, **HashMap** and **ArrayList** are internally implemented inside java? Actually this question was asked to one of my friend in n interview.

Comment: It's opensource you know ? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap` and `ArrayList` are concrete implementations, you can easily find their source code. But the reason for this question was different. Your friend was suppose to know what principles are behind the implementation, what data structures and algorithms. How they affect big O notation?

Question about `InputStream` doesn't make much sense, it's an abstract class. It has several implementations based on different back-ends.

Comment: thanks...but can u give me  light idea about the same i.e datastructures and implementations

Comment: @Maverick: `ArrayList` wraps an array, `HashMap` is based on hashtable. For more, see sources.

Comment: Related to collections, I agree with you, about Input or other IO related implementation I think main point of question was diff between byte by byte reading to byte array reading, like IO vs NIO